# Registry pattern and .net core DI

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I've met a registry pattern, it seems an old one and gut feeling tells something is not good in design, but I can't figure out how to rework it.

There are a few registries like the following:

```
class ClientRegistry 
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, IClient> _items = new Dictionary<string, IClient>();
        public void Register(string key, IClient client)
        {
            _items.Add(key, client);
        }

        public bool ContainsKey(string key) => _items.ContainsKey(key);

        public IClient this[string key]
        {
            get
            {
                if (!_items.ContainsKey(key))
                    throw new ArgumentException($"{key} is not registered");
                return _items[key];
            }
        }
    }


//configuring DI
services.TryAddScoped(x =>
            {
                var registry = new ClientRegistry();
                var client = x.GetRequiredService<ClientA>();
                registry.Register(client.Name, client);
                
                client = x.GetRequiredService<ClientB>();
                registry.Register(client.Name, client);
                //etc.                
            });
```

some usage example:

```
class MultiClientHelper{
    private readonly ClientRegistry _registry;

    public void ForEach<TResult>(
            IEnumerable<string> enumerable, 
            Action<IClient> action)
        {
            enumerable.Where(e => _registry.ContainsKey(e)).ForEach(e => action(_registry[selector(e)]));
        }
}
```

Comment: What's issue you are facing?

Comment: no issue, it works. I need to create another few registries like the above and thinking whether it is a pattern or anti-pattern? If it is a pattern, I doubt because I don't remember it was mentioned anywhere in C# design patterns etc.